# Visual Studio cannot open include file, drops characters from path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, poco-libraries

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 to build a project that uses the Poco libraries.

### Background:

Don't know if this is pertinent, but I'll just mention that I manually downloaded and built Poco (and all the other libs needed), and everything went fine for years. Now I switched to using Miniconda3 to manage my libraries, installing Poco via [`conda install -c conda-forge poco`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poco) and changing the relevant include paths from

```
$(POCO_DIR)/Foundation/include
$(POCO_DIR)/Util/include
...
```

to just

```
$(CONDA_LIBS)/include
```

with the system variable `$(CONDA_LIBS) = D:\CodeLibraries\conda_libs\Library`. This `CONDA_LIBS` directory exists and contains an `include/Poco/` subdirectory with all the Poco header files and subdirs.

### Problem:

The project compiled fine. I got a linker error, and while digging into this I found some odd behavior of Visual Studio 2017:

When I'm moving the cursor to an `#include` directive using any Poco header file, e.g.

```
#include "Poco/DateTime.h"
```

I can *usually* type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open and jump to the file in question.
**This doesn't work anymore**, and I get a popup telling me

> D:\CodeLibraries\conda_libs\Library\include\oco\atetime.h
>   Cannot open file.

Note the missing letters in `\(P)oco\(D)atetime.h`. Note, also, that a file is *found*, but cannot be *opened*.

When I try this with a header file in a subdirectory like

```
#include "Poco/JSON/Parser.h"
```

I get the message

> D:\CodeLibraries\conda_libs\Library\include\oco\son\rser.h
>   Cannot open file.

Note the missing letters "P", "J", and "Pa"(?!) in `(P)oco\(J)SON\(Pa)rser.h`.

#### Additional information:

- The same error pops up when I **drag-and-drop** a Poco header file from the Windows Explorer into Visual Studio **(!)**
- I can open these files from the *Open File* dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)
- I can still use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut to open my own header files in my project, and to open other library header files like `gdal.h` or boost headers
- if I `#include "oco/ateTime.h"` (note the missing letters) and attempt to open it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> I get the expected message "File 'oco/ateTime.h' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths", with the paths listed below including `D:\CodeLibraries\conda_libs\Library/include`.

---

#### Question:

Any idea why both the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut and the drag-and-drop operation fail for Poco header files?

---

**EDIT:**
Please note:

- I'm not asking about generic "File not found" errors: I can usually handle my include and lib paths quite well, thank you
- slashes and backslashes can be used pretty much interchangedly in Visual Studio for the last couple of years at least

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a 3rd party extension messing up your Visual Studio setup? Also have you tried to \, not / ?

Comment: "The project compiled fine. I got a linker error", Can you update the post with the linker errors?

Comment: Linker errors happen when you mix different versions of libraries (dll, lib or object files) and/or it's corresponding header files. This case usually happens when you only to refer the latest headers but not latest libs or vice versa. Please make sure you are linking to the exact version of POCO you have configured in the include paths. If possible please check and update the thread with the previously used POCO version and the POCO you have currently configured through conda. Also check the include and lib paths are properly configured in your visual studio project.

Comment: The current version of POCO mentioned in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poco is 1.9.0.

Comment: One more thing, you have not mentioned whether you have reconfigured the linker paths in your project or not. You have only mentioned the changes in include paths.

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem in VS2019 configured with VS2017 target and configuring POCO paths in conda. I'm getting linker errors related to OpenSSL. But my linker errors are probably due to the fact that I'm linking my project with OpenSSL version 1.1.0j which is possibly wrong. I'm sure the linker errors will go away if I find out and install the exact version of openSSL which the conda version of POCO libraries are built. This simply infers that we will also need to check the openSSL version and link to the exact version in your project if you are using PocoCrypto or PocoNet modules.

Comment: I have no other issues with the same kind of setup except for OpenSSL related linker errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Cannot open File"** error could be due to a misconfiguration in your project include and source paths or due to a third-party extension or maybe even due to a corrupt/buggy IDE, but it has nothing to do with linker errors as you have also mentioned. You have also confirmed that the files are getting compiled, so this is surely some issue with the IDE's built-in code navigator or an extension.

With respect to linker errors, the project Configurations, lib target, library & header file versions you are referring to should match while linking against third-party libraries.

**These are some general checklists for linking third-party libraries:**

1. Runtime library: MT, MTd, MD, MDd, etc
2. Character set: Unicode or Multibyte
3. Target compiler
4. Target Machine
5. Subsystem
6. Whether the third-party library being used has additional dependencies, and you are properly linking the exact version of them.

**These are checklists specific to POCO:**

1. POCO version you are referring to in header files vs linker path
   configurations.
2. OpenSSL version you are linking your project against, if you are
   using SSL, Crypto and NET modules of POCO.

The same setup on my machine (but with VisualStudio 2019 configured for VisualStudio 2017 target) works just fine.

Comment: This answer doesn't offer any suggestions as to why the Poco header files are found when building the project, but not by IntelliSense when editing.

Comment: @ChristianSeverin, "so this is surely some issue with the IDE's built-in code navigator or an extension" in this sentence I simply meant the same IntelliSense issue you are talking about, I have mentioned it as Code navigator instead of Intellisense for simplicity and easy understanding. This happens often even for me whenever the dependency paths are changed and Intellisense fails to update its database. I'm not sure whether we have an option to force a reset of the Intellisense DB. I usually will delete the Intellisense files and restart the IDE.

Comment: Waitwaitwait: you say _"This happens often even for me"_ -- do you mean that you have seen this behaviour as well, that you cannot jump from an `#include` line to the header file, and that an error message pops up with a strangely mangled path?

Comment: @ChristianSeverin, yes, this usually occurs when the dependency paths are reconfigured (ie: when the third-party files are moved to a different location) even when there is no change happened in the dependency files except for the path change. I guess Intellisense is unable to detect that. I have never bothered to report this as a problem to Microsoft. I usually delete the Intellisense database and restart the IDE that forces the reinitialization of Intellisense DB.

Comment: Huh. OK, then I'm sorry I misinterpreted your answer. You might want to edit it to emphasize that you indeed had this problem as well, and what you did to fix it. And I suggest removing the reference to the linker errors, while you're at it... I'll accept your answer and reference your answer in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Odd.

When I returned to the office today, I wanted to look into this again to see if I could find out more about IntelliSense not finding POCO headers and about the odd dropping-characters thing in the error message, but it works now:
yes, I can once more jump to a POCO header file by moving my cursor to the `#include` line and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

No idea if it was restarting VS that fixed this, or fixing the linker error -- which was trivial, BTW, and I might even have done at the side that while writing this question. Unfortunately I either didn't recheck for broken IntelliSense behaviour after the linker fix, or didn't bother recording that IntelliSense still was broken afterwards.
So: no real closure, I'm afraid.

---

**EDIT:** [Ramesh Kambadaasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125581/158371) suggests that a workaround might be to delete the IntelliSense DB file(s) and to restart VS to force a project re-parse. I'll try that next time.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows you should use "\" as a directory seperator, not "/".

My guess is that VS replaces your "/" with "\", then the first letter of every word is an unescaped character.

Try to replace your "/" with "\\".

Comment: I'm mixedly using "/" and both unescaped "\" and escaped "\\" slashes in almost all my projects. I have never come across problems with these. IMO, Visual studio never replaces slashes with escaped characters. It could happen due to some third-party extension though.

Comment: These days VS has no problem with '/' as a separator; it hasn't for the last few versions, IIRC.